# Which whois is the most frequently updated?

Tags: domains, whois

As the domain manager of 200+ domains, it's essential that I am able to get the most up-to-date information for all the domains I manage and monitor. And I realise that, in general, whois sites do not update their databases often at all.

I've been using who.is all this time but the details for domains I look up aren't always recent. What whois database is the most accurate and up-to-date? I've tried looking up a few but it's hard to tell how often each one updates its database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being one who has a similar site, I would have thought who.is or whois.com were the most accurate. Mine is different in that I capture the information at the time of an attack, spam, or other similar event. However, most other sites will re-query the whois data when the page is accessed assuming that there is a measure to ensure that the same whois data is not being requested to often. Some sites subscribe and download bulk whois data from time to time and update their databases that way instead of relying on traffic. With a large site such as these, it is nearly impossible to keep the data 100% fresh. There are limits to whois look-ups and sites have to be careful not to over do it.

The best thing to do is either use `nslookup` in a Windows command window or `nslookup` or `whois` in a terminal window in Linux. This will give you the current whois information. But be sure not to try and make bulk queries or you just may be blacklisted. Spread them out a bit and you should be fine.

Comment: Which whois tool should I use in Linux? I'm using Fedora 20.

Comment: @MissM Both nslookup and whois work fine, but I tend to use whois almost exclusively. There is no difference really. You would have to open a terminal window then type *whois example.com*.

Comment: I tried but it said it couldn't find the command for it so it doesn't appear to be installed. I'll try a different version of Linux next day.

Comment: `nslookup` does DNS queries, which are completely unrelated to whois. In fact a domain name can be registered (and hence appear in registry whois server output) but not be delegated and hence no successful DNS queries can be made for it. And if you are on Linux, you should prefer `dig` over `nslookup`.